# MS Access 2007 Database Application Compatability 32 bit 64 bit Issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, 32bit-64bit

We have a 2007 Access database application that we would like to deploy to a large number of users at various sites with different versions of Access (some without an install of Access and just instructions to install the Access 2007 Run Time) for a data collection effort. We were planning on deploying it as an ACCDE file with compiled VBA code - we noted that users with 2007, 2010 and 2013 could open this file.  However, during testing, we discovered that at least one of our user's computers had 2010 installed but, the 64-bit version of Access/Office and we received the following error message upon trying to open it:

```
This database was created with the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access.  
Please open it with the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access.
```

We are now looking for some alternative options to account for this unforeseen compatibility issue.  The application was developed on a 32-bit version of Access 2007.

If we were to deploy the ACCDB file, instead of the compiled ACCDE version, would 64-bit version of Access still be able to run it? 
For all years 2007-2013?
Also, would users with just the 2007 Access Run Time still be able to open just he ACDDB file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we were to deploy the ACCDB file, instead of the compiled ACCDE version, would 64-bit version of Access still be able to run it?

Generally speaking, yes. Provided that

- there are no 32-bit third-party ActiveX controls being used, and
- calls to the Win32 API (if any) are pointer-safe

then the 64-bit versions of Access will be able to recompile the VBA code automatically when the .accdb file is opened. (They can't do that with the .accde file because the .accde file does not contain the VBA source.)

> Also, would users with just the 2007 Access Run Time still be able to open just he ACDDB file?

I would expect so, particularly since Access 2007 was still 32-bit only (as I recall). Of course, the best way to know for sure would be to try it and see.